# Same Origin Policy and Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, same-origin-policy

Now I know there are a lot of resources about same origin policy, but I just want a straight up answer for my specific query as I am really struggling to understand.

I am using Facebook plugins on my website, these create iframes that are only visible in the DOM when I use chromes inspect element etc.

Is there a way that I can access these iFrames properties/attributes at all, or is it a resounding "NO CHANCE!".  I am spending far too much time on this and I just need to get a final verdict.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't see the iframe content. Chrome inspector just loads 2 different websites in the same time, yours and the plugins one, so you can play with both of them.

Just curious, how would you like to change it?

Answer (score 0):

In general, JavaScript cannot access iframe content from outside of the iframe, unless the page domain and the iframe domain share the same protocol and host and port.  In your case, this could possibly be done using a proxy server to load the iframe content from your domain.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy